# nameerror while using eval with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, eval

i am scraping the python.org website for some info using **beautifulsoup**. I am also trying to get the programme to print the return type of a function

My code is as follows:

```
soup = Soup(gethtml('https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html'))
for function in soup.find_all('dl', {'class': 'function'}):
    try:
        func_name = function.dt['id']
        print eval(func_name).__doc__
```

I am trying to retrieve the function in string format and passing it to eval and getting the return info using `.__doc__`

Which in this case is `string.capwords`

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/GX70/PycharmProjects/assignment/tasks/libscrape.py", line 58, in <module>
    print eval(func_name).__doc__
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `string` on top

```
import string
```

Then

```
In [165]: eval("string.capwords.__doc__")
Out[165]: 'capwords(s [,sep]) -> string\n\n    Split the argument into words using split, capitalize each\n    word using capitalize, and join the capitalized words using\n    join.  If the optional second argument sep is absent or None,\n    runs of whitespace characters are replaced by a single space\n    and leading and trailing whitespace are removed, otherwise\n    sep is used to split and join the words.\n\n    '
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative?

Comment: without import string? `getattr(import_module(func_name.split(".")[0]), func_name.split(".")[1]).__doc__` to use `from importlib import import_module
`

Comment: Thanks that is what i wanted. Any idea how to get types of input parameters?